# How to set Http header Fields using C programming

Tags: c, http, curl, header, libcurl

I have code to save/read an http header, but in my application I want to set and send an http response header to my client. So how can I set an http header response for any request sent by the client?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>

static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    int written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
    return written;
}

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl_handle;
    static const char *headerfilename = "head.txt";
    FILE *headerfile;
    static const char *bodyfilename = "body.txt";
    FILE *bodyfile;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    /* init the curl session */ 

    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

    /* set URL to get */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.co.in");

    /* no progress meter please */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);

    /* send all data to this function  */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

    /* open the files */
    headerfile = fopen(headerfilename,"wb");
    if (headerfile == NULL) {
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
        return -1;
    }
    bodyfile = fopen(bodyfilename,"wb");
    if (bodyfile == NULL) {
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
        return -1;
    }

    /* we want the headers be written to this file handle */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle,   CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, headerfile);

    /* we want the body be written to this file handle instead of stdout */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle,   CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, bodyfile);

    /* get it! */ 
    curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

    /* close the header file */ 
    fclose(headerfile);

    /* close the body file */ 
    fclose(bodyfile);

    /* cleanup curl stuff */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"for any request"* -> http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: curl comes with some examples, e.g. http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html , is that what you need ?

Comment: @nos Correct me if I'm wrong, but that's just for modifying a client request, not for composing a server response.  AFAIK, curl just implements stuff for clients, not servers.

Comment: Subject should be about Curl, not C. You could easily set a HTTP header field using C programming by using ordinary strings and a socket. But no, that's not what this is about. This is about a specific API.

Comment: i have already checked curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html but i wanna implement my own response for any header request.

Comment: You may want to be a lot  more specific.  As it stands a valid answer is `write(socket_fd,msg,strlen(msg));`

Answer (score 0):

As has been said in comments:

libcurl is a client-side library for doing the HTTP request. It will not help you implement the server *response*.

The server response will have to be sent by the server-side implementation and you haven't shown that or even explained how that is implemented. You cannot implement the server-side using libcurl.

Comment: @Deniel Stenberg SO, how can i implement simple code for that in server side without using libcurl, is there any other library available for that??......Please suggest me.....

Comment: There are a bazillion different HTTP server solutions already, open source and commercial.